# For Looping error in pyspark

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyspark, ipython, apache-spark-sql

I am facing the following problem:
I have a list which I need to compare with the elements of a column in a dataframe(acc_name). I am using the following looping function but it only returns me 1 record when it should provide me 30.
Using Pyspark

```
 bs_list = 
['AC_E11','AC_E12','AC_E13','AC_E135','AC_E14','AC_E15','AC_E155','AC_E157',
 'AC_E16','AC_E163','AC_E165','AC_E17','AC_E175','AC_E180','AC_E185',   'AC_E215','AC_E22','AC_E225','AC_E23','AC_E23112','AC_E235','AC_E245','AC_E258','AC_E25','AC_E26','AC_E265','AC_E27','AC_E275','AC_E31','AC_E39','AC_E29']


    for i in bs_list:
            bs_acc1 = (acc\
                       .filter(i == acc.acc_name)
                       .select(acc.acc_name,acc.acc_description)
                      )
```

the bs_list elements are subset of acc_name column. I am trying to create a new DF which will have the following 2 Columns acc_name, acc_description. It will only contain details of the value of elements present in list bs_list
Please let me know where I am going wrong?

Comment: You are trying to iterate the RDD for elements in the list. Instead try to iterate the list with each element in the RDD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats because , in loop everytime you filter on `i`, you are creating a new dataframe bs_acc1. So it must be showing you only 1 row belonging to last value in bs_list i.e. row for `'AC_E29'`

one way to do it is repeat union with itself, so previous results also remain in the dataframe like -

```
# create a empty dataframe, give schema which is appropriate to your data below

bs_acc1 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(sc.emptyRDD(), schema)

for i in bs_list:
            bs_acc1 = bs_acc1.union(
                         acc\
                            .filter(i == acc_fil.acc_name)
                            .select(acc.acc_name,acc.acc_description)
                       )
```

better way is not doing loop at all -

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
bs_acc1 = acc.where(acc.acc_name.isin(bs_list))
```

Comment: I tried the second solution I am getting the following error: condition should be string or Column

Comment: sorry, My bad, There is even better way. See my updated answer above

Comment: I tried both solution. Both worked. This makes it clear where I was going wrong . Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can also transform `bs_list` to dataframe with column `acc_name` and then just do join to `acc` dataframe.

```
bs_rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(bs_list)
bs_df = bs_rdd.map(lambda x: Row(**{'acc_name':x})).toDF()
bs_join_df = bs_df.join(acc, on='acc_name')
bs_join_df.show()
```